# Ionic horizontal scroll not working with iOS 10

Tags: cordova, scroll, ionic-framework, horizontal-scrolling, ios10

Horizontal scroll on my ionic tablet app is not working on iOS 10, still works fine on iOS 8 and 9. Using cordova-ios 4.1.1. When I try to pull the list to the left the scroll just bounces immediately.

```
<ion-scroll direction="x" scrollbar-x="false" id="notebooks-quick-view">
    <notebook-quick-view ng-repeat="notebook in notebooks"></notebook-quick-view>
</ion-scroll>
```

Comment: Once I got rid of ```position: absolute``` on the ion-scroll then it worked fine once again

Comment: I can confirm - just recieved client's complaints that overflow scrolling is not working on multiple elements in our mobile app. Will try the fix you suggested.